# How to return a response from a Future in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In a Widget I call a future to enable me to send a Post request using http.Client and a body made up of several fields that a user enters via TextFields;

The call;

```
var result =
OrderEvent()
     .get(
     body);
```

I have a class, named OrderEvent, that gets called above and handles the POST request to my API. The OrderEvent.get is a Future and it returns only a 'Success' at the moment, which is a bool;

```
class OrderEvent {
late final OrderReference data;
late final resultBody;
var client = http.Client();
var url = sendOrderURL;
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
};

Future<dynamic> get(String orderBody) async {
  var response = await client.post(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: headers,
  body: orderBody,
);

var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

OrderEventResponse orderResponse = OrderEventResponse.fromJson(data);

// Stores success as bool
var success = orderResponse.success;
// Stores external Order Id
var externalOrderId = orderResponse.externalOrderId;
// Stores SOL generated deliveryNote number
var deliveryNoteNo = orderResponse.deliveryNoteNo;
// Stores delivery date of generated delivery note
var deliveryDate = orderResponse.deliveryDate;
// Stores article message within response
var articleResponseMessage = orderResponse.articleResponseMessage.toString();

if(articleResponseMessage == "[No rows to approve]")
 {
   success = true;
 }

if (success)
  return success;
else
  return Future.error(
      "Order could not be submitted to SOL"); //articleResponseMessage);
 }
}
```

Within the above method i get the response data based on the repsonse of the POST request by using a method that accepts the http.Client response.body.  Below is the class that i use;

```
List<OrderEventResponse> orderEventResponseFromJson(String val) =>
    List<OrderEventResponse>.from(
        json.decode(val).map((val) => OrderEventResponse.fromJson(val)));

@JsonSerializable()
class OrderEventResponse {
 final bool success;
 final String externalOrderId;
 final int deliveryNoteNo;
 final deliveryDate;
 final List articleResponseMessage;

OrderEventResponse(
  {required this.success,
  required this.externalOrderId,
  required this.deliveryNoteNo,
  required this.deliveryDate,
  required this.articleResponseMessage});

factory OrderEventResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return OrderEventResponse(
    success: json['success'] ?? false,
    externalOrderId: json['externalOrderId'] ?? '',
    deliveryNoteNo: json['deliveryNoteNo'] ?? 0,
    deliveryDate: json['deliveryDate'] ?? '',
    articleResponseMessage: json['messages'] ?? []);
 }
}
```

My question is, how can i return the entire orderResponse result to the call so i can access both the sucess and articleResponseMessage, at present the result is just the success bool and i need to be able to see if there are any messages returned from the API to go with a FALSE success;

Example;

```
 var result =
 OrderEvent()
  .get(
  body);

 var resultSuccess = result.success;
 var resultMessages = result.articleResponseMessage.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to return a `Future` with a value of any type:

```dart
Future<OrderEventResponse> get(String orderBody) async {
  // ...
  OrderEventResponse orderResponse = OrderEventResponse.fromJson(data);
  // ...
  return orderResponse;
}
```

Note the return type of `Future<OrderEventResponse>`.

Now, decide on an error-handling strategy. There are two ways you might decide to handle errors.

#### 1. Return `null`

```dart
Future<OrderEventResponse?> get(String orderBody) async {
  // ...
  if (success)
    return orderResponse;
  else
    return null;
}
```

#### 2. Throw an exception

```dart
Future<OrderEventResponse> get(String orderBody) async {
  // ...
  if (success)
    return orderResponse;
  else
    throw Exception("Order could not be submitted to SOL");
}
```

If unsure, I'd suggest leaning toward throwing an exception. Also, consider creating a specific exception subclass rather than using the generic `Exception` depicted in the above example.

Additionally, I suggest the following:

- Read [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)
- Avoid using `dynamic` unless you have a very clear, specific, and convincing reason to do so. There are some very good reasons for using `dynamic` on occasion, but be aware that using it defeats Dart's excellent static type checking for those things which are declared `dynamic`, which is likely not advantageous, especially if you're just starting with Dart.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I get that i can return the orderResponse, that's not the real issue, the issue i have is how i can then use the several fields i have within the OrderEventResponse model. Success, delivery date, order Id etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this one myself, after reading back through my code.

This is how i return the OrderResponse from my Future, that gives me access to the data i require.  I was completely missing the AWAIT!! Doh.

```
var result =
OrderEvent()
 .get(
 body);
                                                                          
**OrderEventResponse eventResponse = await result;
var success = eventResponse.success;
var message = eventResponse.articleResponseMessage.toString();**
```